# Email Forwarding Unsubscribe Prevention in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Hi is there a way to prevent hide a unsubscribe or manage preferences page in the event a person forwards an email.  We use Marketing Cloud in our team.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you send an email to a subscriber, all links etc are unique to that subscriber, email etc.

If a subscriber decides to forward their email onto a 3rd party (using email client forward button) then any activity the 3rd party does to that email/links etc is seen as though the original subscriber performed this (including unsubscribe)

Unless you use the SFMC Forward to a Friend functionality would the links become unique to the forwarded recipient.

There is no way of dynamically changing it hiding links if an email if it's been forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

The fear of having a forwarded email recipient unsubscribe your primary subscriber is, I believe, not something to actually worry about.

To answer your question - no, there is no way to have the link change or disappear if the email is forwarded.

That being said - if the email *is* forwarded, then it's being sent from an existing subscriber to someone that they think may be interested in the content. You might actually consider an opt-in link down there in the footer.

And just in case the forwarded recipient *does* click to unsubscribe your original recipient...you can take some preventative actions:

- On the unsubscribe page, display the email that's being unsubscribed. Most people will see that it is not their email and back away.
- Send a transactional email post unsubscribe confirming the opt out and giving instructions (in case the opt out was in error or in case they want to opt back in at a later date). Your primary subscriber should get this and will most likely opt back in (and then tease their friend for unsubscribing them).